# How to find the zeros of $f(x,y)$ over a field?

Tags: roots, surfaces

**Solution of surface or two variable polynomial:**

Suppose consider the expression $f(x,y)=\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} a_{ij}x^iy^j \in k[x,y]$ over a field $k$.

I am interested in the zeros of $f(x,y)$.

If we plot $f(x,y)$ in a $3D$ space, it will be a surface.

So the zeros of $f(x,y)$ are obtained by intersecting with $z=0$ plane.

Ofcourse, $z=0$ over the other two axes.

In other words, if $f(x,y)$ lie above the $xy$-plane, then no zeros of $f(x,y)$ are there in $k$.

Is it enough to observe ?

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: That’s true but it only makes sense over an ordered field like $\mathbb{R}$ and in any case it’s very incomplete as a description. It’s actually an open problem to give an algorithm to do this when $k = \mathbb{Q}$. Other fields are easier. What fields are you interested in?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Thanks,  what about $p$-adic field ? How to analyze then ?

Comment: You can look for solutions $\mod p$ then try to lift them using a multivariate version of Hensel’s lemma, e.g.: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/multivarhensel.pdf

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Thanks, I have it.  Actually my purpose is to discuss roots of p-adic power series in its maximal ideal. Kindly see my main question-https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372512/how-to-analyze-the-roots-of-two-variable-p-adic-power-series-fx-y-in-the-m